# java not able to call a second class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to access a method from a class in java from my main class. The compiler seems to not understand what I am doing.

It shows the compiler error off: `error cannot find symbol`on the line  `mp = new getDataForDisplay(i);`

What I am trying to do is access this method which assigns values to several global variables of that class to draw a rectangle.

This code is from my main class (simplified in certain areas)

```
main class
-some other classes here
-this is in my actionlistener...removed some irrelevant parts
  //show graph
            f1.add(new mainPanel(numProcc)); //shows data for graph
            f1.pack();
            processDetail.dispose();
            //call up process builder
            connect2c c = new connect2c (); // compile and run the C code

            int i = 0;
            String[] value = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };
            mainPanel mp;
            while (i < numProcc)
            {
                c.returnData(value[i]);
                mp = new getDataForDisplay(i);
                //openFile f = new openFile (value[i]);
                i++;
            }
```

**If you notice on the fifth line, I somehow manage to connect to the mainPanel class. I found this code online somewhere**

This is the class I am trying to access, the method I am trying to access is `getDataForDisplay()`

```
class mainPanel extends JPanel
{
    int xCoor =0;
    int yCoor =0;
    int width =0;
    int height =0;
    public mainPanel(int x)
    {
       //constructor stuff here
    }

    public void getDataForDisplay (int a) 
    {
    //store in global variable

    //width = num of processes x 20
    //rect ->x,y,width,height
    //int a -> how many quantums, not using yet
    xCoor = 100;
    yCoor = 150;
    width = 50;
    height = 50;

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);   

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect (xCoor, yCoor, width, height);

    }  
}
```

Comment: have you imported the class `mainPanel ` ?
If not you can use the fully qualified className for initialization

Comment: @SashiKant are you referrring to mainPanel mp ?

Comment: Does your main class include that `mainPanel` class, in the import declaration?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: Three problems: 1) You appear not to have declared the `mp` variable (at least in the code we've seen); 2) You're using `getDataForDisplay` as if it were the name of a *type* rather than a method; you almost certainly want to ditch the `new` there; 3) `getDataForDisplay` is a void method, so what do you expect the assignment to do? Additionally, I'd strongly advise you to start following Java naming conventions *right now* and lay your source code out with consistent indentation.

Comment: @SashiKant this is the first line mainpanel shows       f1.add(new mainPanel(numProcc)); //shows data for graph

Comment: Please don't try to write java code copy-pasting stuff found on the internet without knowing the (a) language, it's really unlikely that you'll end up with something working. Really.

Comment: Just posted a tutorial I think should be helpful for you. Also, understand that you cannot call `new` on `getDataForDisplay(int)`. You can only call new with class `constructors`. If you want to use this method outside of the class, you should make it static. Then you can access it like `mainPanel.getDataForDisplay(1)` in another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line: `mp = new getDataForDisplay(i);` has plenty of syntactical errors: `new someMethodCall(...)` isn't allowed, `getDataForDisplay(...)` has returntype void, etc.. Correct would be

```
mp = new MainPanel();
mp.getDataForDisplay();
```

Answer (score 0):

`mp = new getDataForDisplay(i);` makes no sense,

- remove the `new` keyword if you want to call that method
- `mainPanel mp = new mainPanel();` if you want to create an object of type `mainPanel`
- according to conventions, class names should start with uppercase, so `mainPanel` should be `MainPanel`

If you don't get the difference between class, object, methods, instantiation... well, I'd start from that before going any further